# Differences between 'child_added' and 'value' firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am seeing a tad difference between `child_added` and `value` when returning data in firebase. Using `value` I can test to see if `snapshot.val()` has returned something or not using it like this:

Fetching Data:

```
ref.orderByChild('appUserName')
    .equalTo(issuer)
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();
      if (value) { 
          // Has Value...
      }else{
          //Has No Value...
      }
```

Data Structure:

```
AppUsers --
    234jl23jl4kj23 --
        data --
            //.. data
        userName : "testUser1",
        userPass: "password123"
    9873h23foiu34u
        //same structure
    o8987s52df134o
        //same structure
```

If I `console.log` how the value has returned `snapshot.val()` it returns the data on the level of the generated key:

```
{234jl23jl4kj23 --
    {data --
        //.. data
    userName : "testUser1",
    userPass: "password123"}}
```

If I get the data using `child_added`:

```
ref.orderByChild('appUserName')
    .equalTo(issuer)
    .once('child_added')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      var value = snapshot.val();
      if (value) { 
          // Has Value...
      }else{
          //Has No Value...
      }
```

It wont even go into the `.then` function if `issuer` is not found as a value to `appUserName`, so I cant see in the firebase function if it got a value or not. Also the way `child_added` gets data is one level deeper. Instead of returning at the generated key it returns the values in that key:

```
{data --
   //.. data
userName : "testUser1",
userPass: "password123"}
```

I would prefer to use it this way because it would be one less loop I would have to check to first get the data inside of the key, then loop through the objects in the data spot. However if `issuer` is not in `appUserName` it wont go into the function for me to even do an `if` `else`

Is there a way to drill in as deep as `child_added` without looping but still be able to do an `if else` to check if the `snapshot.val()` has anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `child_added` event fires for each matching child under the node that you query. If there are no matching children, it will not fire.

This means that to test whether a node exists, you must use a `value` handler. And since a query can have multiple results, you will need to loop over the children.

Comment: Ah, that does make sense then. Thanks.