# Print All Children Columns from Firebase - iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I have 2 records in my users table

[image]

This code below

```
let fcmTokenRef = Database.database().reference().root.child("users").child(id!).child("fcmToken")
fcmTokenRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(">>",snapshot)
})
```

will print out the token of a child

[image]

How do I adjust my code to print **all** the tokens for all my children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let fcmTokenRef = Database.database().reference().root.child("users").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in 
      print(">>",snapshot)

      let dic = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
      Array(dic.values).forEach { 
        let str = $0["fcmToken"] as! String
        print(str)
     }
})
```

Comment: for 1 observe replace `observe` with `observeSingleEvent`

Comment: Your code compile fine, but stuck here when running on a phone. : https://i.imgur.com/LxtzS7C.png

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Did I miss any part of your code ?

Comment: You updated code compiled perfect, and run perfectly on the phone. I got these on my console now . https://i.imgur.com/4PqScly.png

Comment: What is `$0` mean ?

Comment: it's like for loop item in  `for item in arr` here `$0=item`

Comment: What type is this `$0["fcmToken"]` ?  Is there a way to find out ?

Answer (score 1):

You’re requesting a onetime read, hence you’re reading the data once. You need to use `.childAdded`

Try this:

```
let fcmTokenRef = Database.database().reference().child(“users”)
    fcmTokenRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(">>",snapshot)
     guard let data = snapshot as? NSDictionary else {return}
     var each_token = data[“fcmToken”] as? String
     print(“all tokens: \(each_token!)”)
})
```

@puf says something very important: 
[differences between child added and value firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40435190/differences-between-child-added-and-value-firebase)

> The child_added event fires for each matching child under the node that you query. If there are no matching children, it will not fire.

Comment: @kyo isn’t needed, childAdded loops through every child in the collection. So nothing to worry

Comment: If it is not why leave it as part of your answer ? can I remove it ?

Comment: Also your suggested code seems malformed. See this error : https://i.imgur.com/EKfediu.png

Comment: Updated, also update the curlies with the ones xcode suggest. Thanks

Comment: I tried your code, it seems to compile fine, but when run in iPhone, it crash and showed me this error : https://i.imgur.com/vhwEWpz.png

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? Did I miss any part of your code ?

Comment: @kyo updated, this time it should work with no errors at all